# How to populate a tableview that contain CheckBox in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview

I created a `TableView` that I populated with an `ObservableList`,
Some column of my table are `CheckBox` and I want is that the `CheckBox` bind with the model object that I had created.
Until now the result that I get is: 
If it's text I can see the result but if it is `CheckBox` is always unchecked

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exampla of a checkbox in a tableview:

1. The item shown in the table: Member

   ```
   public class Member {
       private StringProperty myName;
       private BooleanProperty myCheck;

       public Member(String name, boolean checked) {
           myName = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
           myCheck = new SimpleBooleanProperty(checked);
       }

       public StringProperty nameProperty() { return myName; }    
       public BooleanProperty checkProperty() { return myCheck; }
   }
   ```
2. The Table: (Now using the built in class CheckBoxTableCell, thanks to James.D)

   ```
   ObservableList<Member> members = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

   members.add(new Member("peter", true));
   members.add(new Member("gernot", true));
   members.add(new Member("fritz", false));
   for (int i = 1000; i < 2000; i++) members.add(new Member("N"+i, (i%5==0)));

   TableView<Member> table = new TableView<Member>();
   table.prefHeightProperty().bind(box.heightProperty());
   table.setItems(members);

   TableColumn<Member,String> c1 = new TableColumn<Member,String>("Name");
   c1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Member,String>("name"));
   table.getColumns().add(c1);

   TableColumn<Member,Boolean> c2 = new TableColumn<Member,Boolean>("Membership");
   c2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Member,Boolean>("check"));
   c2.setCellFactory(column -> new CheckBoxTableCell()); 
   table.getColumns().add(c2);

   pane.getChildren().addAll(table);
   ```
3. Result:

[image]

Comment: There is a [built-in class for this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html).

Comment: Thank you a lot,it's works, but I want to know what is the différence between SimpleStringProperty nad StringProperty

Comment: I tried them and I think that SimpleStringProperty, for example, allowed me to modified the data, but with StringProperty I cannot do that.                                                                      
 If what I say is true then, what I really want is to show to the user what he had made, and in the same time allowed him to change it if he want to

Comment: `StringProperty` is an abstract class; `SimpleStringProperty` is a full implementation.

Comment: So how can I use the SimpleString Property to produce the same effect ?

Comment: @James_D: I updated the answer to use the CheckBoxTableCell, THX

Comment: @eniniz as noted by James_D the StringProperty is an abstract class, not implementing all required methods like bind(), isBound(), ... 11 in total. You might extend the StringProperty by your own but then you have to implement all these methods. SimpleStringProperty already provides an implementation for these methods to make things simpler.

Comment: You should typically use `StringProperty` as the reference type, and just use the implementation class as the runtime type (i.e. to instantiate the object). This is what @Jens-PeterHaack does in the code he provides: `private StringProperty myName;` and `myName = new SimpleStringProperty(...);`

Comment: is there a simple way to get all the rows with ticked membership for example?